# MySQL - Multi-threaded Update (no thread updates the same id) but having Deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, sql-update, deadlock

I have a multi threaded java program that is running update statements on my MySQL DB. When I use threads I get deadlock although I am never updating the same rows in any two threads. For each time this query is ran field_a is different so why would I have lock issues?

```
thread1: field_a - 'A'
thread2: field_a - 'B'
thread3: field_a - 'C'
```

I am running a query like this

```
 UPDATE table as t, 
            (
             SELECT field_a,
                   field_b,
                   TRUNCATE(AVG(Sumfield_c), 2) avgfield_c,
                   TRUNCATE(AVG(Sumfield_d), 2) avgfield_d
             FROM
              (SELECT field_a,
                      field_b,
                      DateString,
                      sum(field_c) Sumfield_c,
                      sum(field_d) Sumfield_d
               FROM table
               WHERE DateString > DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 22), '%Y%m%d') and field_a = ? and id <= ?
               GROUP BY field_a,
               field_b,
                        DateString) A
             GROUP BY field_a,
                     field_b
            ) as temp
             SET t.Avgfield_c = temp.avgfield_c, t.Avgfield_d = temp.avgfield_d WHERE t.field_a = temp.field_a and t.field_b = temp.field_b and t.id > ?;
```

Comment: What db engine you use for the tables? If they are myisam it locks the whole table, innodb allows row level locking. If the problem is in your java code and not on database level then you need to provide the java code ;)

Comment: My engine is InnoDB. I don't think there is any problem with my java code. I have other multi-threaded processes with insert statements instead of update statements where the code is basically identical besides the Insert vs Update and it works fine. This is the first time I am doing updates and now I am facing deadlock. I think it's the query. I am hoping there is some index I can create to solve the issue if anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours I got it working by creating a new index.

CREATE INDEX newIndex ON table (fieldA, fieldB);

Hope this helps someone in the future running a similar query with threading.